Jaspersoft Studio Error Connecting to ODBC Data Connection
I am trying to transition from Jasper Reports 5.6.0 to Jaspersoft Studio 6.2.1.3 Community version. I have navigated to Java Build Path and imported JDBC.jar file into class path.
When trying to set up my data connection I get the following console message:
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver cannot be found by net.sf.jasperreports_6.21.3.final
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.getConnection(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:199)
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.contributeParameters(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:125)
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.AbstractDataAdapterService.test(AbstractDataAdapterService.java:120)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.data.wizard.AbstractDataAdapterWizard$3.runOperations(AbstractDataAdapterWizard.java:153)
at com.jaspersoft.studio.utils.jobs.CheckedRunnableWithProgress$1.run(CheckedRunnableWithProgress.java:50)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver cannot be found by net.sf.jasperreports_6.21.3.final
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.generateException(BundleLoader.java:541)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass0(BundleLoader.java:536)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:416)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:168)
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRClassLoader.loadClassForRealName(JRClassLoader.java:208)
at net.sf.jasperreports.data.jdbc.JdbcDataAdapterService.getConnection(JdbcDataAdapterService.java:158)
... 5 more

Does this answer your question? java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver Exception occurring. Why?
